# Post data not being sent to backend api correctly?

Tags: c#

Trying to run a post request and no data is being sent, even though passing it through? The backend is reporting no post data was sent and I've checked it doesn't seem to send it?

I have doubled checked everything but I don't understand why? StackOverflow keeps asking me for more description so sorry for the long explanation.

```
var response = HttpFactory.PerformHttpWebRequest("http://localhost:8000/api/cache"
new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "item", Username },
    { "name", Name },
    { "picture", Picture },
    { "additional_data", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MetaData) },
}, "POST");



private static HttpResponse PerformHttpWebRequest(
    string url, 
    IDictionary<string, string> data = default, 
    string method = "GET"
)
{
    if (method == "GET" && data != null)
    {
        url += "?" + string.Join("&", data.Select((x) => x.Key + "=" + x.Value));
    }

    LAST_PROCESSED = url;

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        if (data != null && method == "POST")
        {
            byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Join("&", data.Select((x) => x.Key + "=" + x.Value)));

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
            }
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return new HttpResponse(url, response.StatusCode, reader.ReadToEnd());
        }   
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;

        if (response == null)
        {
            return new HttpResponse(url, default, default, we);
        }

        var reponseStream = new StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream());

        return new HttpResponse(url, response.StatusCode, reponseStream.ReadToEnd());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new HttpResponse(url, default, default, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";` but actually POSTing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Can you try changing that?